# Running simple Hadoop command via php

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I run simple hadoop ls command wrapped via php, it is not executing. Any suggestion?

cat foo.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

exec("hadoop fs -ls /");

?>
```

When I run it nothing happens:

```
php foo.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo exec("hadoop fs -ls /");
```

you need to tell php to do something with the result!

Comment: When I run "hadoop fs -ls /" outside of the script I get many directories but when I run from within php, all I get is "drwxrwxr-x   - test   hadoop          0 2013-05-15 12:01 /usr"

Comment: @Rio is php set up to run in safe mode?

Comment: not sure how can i test that? how to get out of safe mode?

Comment: It is not in safe mode. I tested by: #!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
   echo " safe mode is on";
}else{
   echo "not in safe mode";
}

?>

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the code below using php and it is runing fine.

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/HBase/hbase-1.2.4/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator="," -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf tem hdfs://master:9000/user/file.txt';
var_dump(shell_exec($cmd));
```